# C++ coming from Java and Objective-C

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, porting

So, I know both Java and Objective-C quite well, but (perhaps strangely) never really learned C++. Obviously, the languages are all related, but there are syntactical differences that I don't fully understand. Is there a nice document that describes the basics of C++, but still assumes the learner knows a programming language? Perhaps even a tutorial that aims to describe the differences between the languages. This is what I'm looking for.

Also, is there a good tutorial on how to use C++ code inside a Mac or iOS app? The reason I feel the need to learn C++ is I'm trying to port a C++ program, and I heard you can use C++ code and just wrap it in an Obj-C GUI. Could someone point me to some documentation/tutorials on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Uhuh, if you think the only differences between Java and C++ are syntactical you'll be in for a heck of a ride (just writing a correct assignment operator, move semantics,..). Anyways sorry no I haven't see such a tutorial - probably because there are many concepts in C++ that can't be mapped to Java..

Comment: If you're interested in the Mac, isn't Objective-C++ basically Objective-C with most of C++ added? The whole point being to allow Objective-C and C++ to be mixed?

Comment: @Voo I didn't mean that at all. I understand there are differences between all three languages, but I'm interested in investing the time to learn another. Pointers are a biggie, for one example, but those are covered in Objective-C. I'm sure there are points not in either language, but I understand that, and I'm willing to invest the time to learn the new concepts.

Comment: @Jake Well in that case, I'd go with Kerrek's suggestion. That should teach you the concepts in C++ nicely (without some new features, but then it's probably a really good idea to stay far away from stuff like move semantics anyhow). As an example good C++ rarely needs pointers (there are exceptions, especially for low level stuff) - you can write C in C++, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: @Voo: Most people have absolutely no clue at all what the "syntax of a programming language" actually is.

Comment: One thought - current C++ books mostly cover C++98, with a few covering TR1 features etc. With C++0x/11 imminent, many people are already starting that transition. It may be a bad time to learn the old C++98 quirks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the languages of this family are all related, that does not mean that you can casually move from one to the other and expect to write beautiful code. You have to learn the language's idioms and idiosyncrasies, and experience its strengths and way of thinking.

I would recommend reading Stroustrup's original book (a modern edition, of course). It's the most definitive reference (short of the actual standard) and it is very clearly written. The benefit of this approach is that you will be taught to think "how would I do this in C++", rather than "how do I transliterate this piece of Java code to make it compile". (Also this approach does away with any risk you might have of thinking you should <s>"learn C first"</s>. Don't.)

On MacOSX, either download and build the free GCC, or get XCode (which comes with GCC). For iOS I don't know, I have a suspicion that you cannot deploy native code on it.

Comment: Well put. Stroustrup really widens the C/C++ gap in that text.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I agree with it. I don't expect it to be a super simple thing. And I don't at all intend to learn this to "transliterate" Java code.

Comment: @Jake: If you're already familiar with programming, you'll breeze through the book in no time. You can skip most of the library reference on a first reading. I bet you won't take a lot more than an afternoon and coffee to get the basics. And you'll feel all the much better for it, promise!

Comment: I think of Stroustrup as a reference book. Actually reading it as a tutorial seems like *very* hard work. I don't think I've ever read more than a few consecutive pages in one go. That said, I've found most language tutorials pretty hard-going for a long time - they mostly seem to explain the seemingly obvious as if it were an incomprehensible concept beyond human imagining. Video tutorials work better - you can pay 10% attention while the video keeps running, then pay 100% attention when something interesting comes along.

Comment: @Steve: If you're already an experienced programmer in Java and ObjC, I would seriously give the book a shot -- it's concise, but very clear and it has all the right ideas in there. Surely there are many other good books, but if you can learn from the source, all the better for you, and that's why it'd be my first recommendation. If it's too dense or opaque, we can always rethink and look at other books, of course, but that should not discourage anyone from opening Stroustrup.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. I already have Xcode for my Obj-C programming, so that's already good. Thanks again for the help, everyone!

Comment: @Kerrek - I'm already an experienced C++ programmer, actually - 12 years plus. I *have* needed to do some C++ tutorial stuff recently, for C++0x. There's some videos on channel9.msdn.com - Stephan T Lavavej, Standard Template Library series - that I found useful (but incomplete) for that. I do think every C++ dev should have a copy of Stroustrup, but I also think it might easily scare off newbies.

Comment: @Steve: Haha, STL is definitely worth watching every minute of. I suppose we should wait and see if there'll be a new version of Stroustrup that reflects the new standard. That'll be nice...

Comment: @Kerreck - According to Stroustrups FAQ, we'll be waiting until around Summer 2012. http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#4th

Comment: @Steve: Thanks! Good link. Oh, here's the Stroustrup himself: "The C++ Programming Language is primarily written for experienced programmers who wants to learn C++." That doesn't sound all that terrifying :-)

Comment: @Kerrek - depends how good a judge Stroustrup is of these things. If he's taking it for granted that an experienced programmer will dip in from time to time, discovering what's different to what he already knows and how to use it, maybe he's a better judge than I give him credit for. I tend to assume tutorials should be read linearly from start to finish.

Comment: While Stroustrup's book is "the authority", I find Lippman's "C++ Primer" (4th edition) to be infintely more readable & usable, and Koenig/Moo's "Accelerated C++" a very worthwhile "crash course" in how to learn C++ properly, i.e. doing things "the C++ way".

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a pure C++ route, the quality of the material being the guide rather than finding ObjC+Java->C++ material.

At the university I am working for we have tried both ways for teaching C++ to students with a lot of programming experience, in particular Java experience, for obvious reasons.

The conclusion was that the specialized course did no better in teaching C++ than the generic one with some extra exercise materials. It's the quality of the teaching materials that matters.

Edit: You will probably receive a lot of good answers on the actual differences, also Voo's comment on your question is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I know what you feel - to have already worked on a couple of languages and learning C++. I was in the same boat too. While I was thinking for a while that it should be easy for me to learn it right away, it wasn't all that easy. So then I went back to the basics and started as a fresher to learn C++. 'C++ Primer' is an extremely good book to start with. Since you know most of the basics of programming, some of the first few chapters can be skimmed through. Once you are through with this, I'd recommend 'Effective C++' book and the C++ FAQs maintained here [http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/].

In fact, you could go through this FAQ first and see how much of it makes sense, and use that as a guide for figuring out where to do a deep dive.

HTH, K

Comment: Don't ever recommend to "skim" through chapters of any book. Especially with C++, where the tiniest things can lead to disasters. It's important to read every chapter carefully, even the one about operators, as most of them usually have this "Really? Damn, didn't know that.." kind of information that can save you a huge headache at times. For example, somebody who "skimmed" through such a chapter might fail to detect what's wrong with something like std::cout << (i > j) ? i : j; which will always print 0 or 1, contrary to common expectations.

Comment: @MisterSir - hmmm - I'd have thought any programmer should know that the precedence of some operators is non-obvious, the "what it should be" varies from person to person, and that's why (for readability if nothing else) you shouldn't be too sparing with your parens. I agree to a degree with the point of your comment, but reading something cover-to-cover while bored stiff isn't going to get anything lodged into your memory. Falling asleep, or staring zombie-like at the page, isn't the same as learning.

Comment: @MisterSir - I'd say your comment strongly suggests that learners should do thorough testing of every example program they write. When you find something unexpected, *then* you can do the research and the "why" will stick much better in memory.

Comment: @Steve314 - When I said to read carefully I didn't mean to such extent. Reading carefully means making sure you aren't skipping important things. Nothing hard with proper reading skills that will help you determine which lines have important information and which don't.