# When to Start Learning C++

Tags: c++

I've been coding in Java and C# for about 4-5 months now. Great languages, but I feel like I'm really ready to take the next step. I'm anxious to begin learning c++, and I've already started to do so, but I'm admittedly having a hard time with it. It really does take a lot more effort to learn and accomplish anything when using it, and I feel like I'm really going nowhere. What should I do? Should I just continue programming with Java? Please, if this is the case give a good reason for this: I honestly would rather learn C++ because of what it forces me to do, and also of what I can learn in the process.

If I *should* continue with C++, the question here is...where should I start? Most of the tutorials I've been looking at (Memory Pools, XML Parsing, etc.) is all stuff which has gone way in and over my head.

I also run Linux only, so as far as any .NET goes, it's pretty much limited to MonoDevelop 2.4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ coming from Java and Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643550/c-coming-from-java-and-objective-c)

Comment: Are you trying to achieve anything in particular? If you just want to have fun in the sun, learn Python or Perl :-)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow for "tutorial c++ books" and you will get a lot of great information.

Comment: Try making a simple data structure program... like a linkedlist or queue or stack, or trees. Then job scheduler using the linkedlist. And then you can learn more about networking..synchronization..

Comment: There's no good way to answer your question without providing more information about what you want to do. Like Kerrek pointed out, if you just want to have fun coding, I'd definitely recommend a dynamic high-level language. Besides Python and Perl, a couple other fun languages that are also really popular include Ruby and Javascript.

Comment: I cannot give enough praise to the book "C++ for programmers". It really helped me learn c++, and it is designed for people with previous programming language exposure.

Comment: If you are interested in what's going behind the scenes then starting with (a couple of months of) C might be better and then on top of that you can learn all the C++ stuff... if you just want to learn something new, but not really interested in high performance then pick Python and Ruby, in both of them you can write much more compact and elegant code than Java or C#.

Comment: I want to learn how to develop games. That's my main end goal I'd say. That and operating system development is what interests me quite a bit. Still, C++ is a beast, as they say.

Comment: @Holland: You don't need to use C++ to develop games or OSs. More and more of that is done using managed languages now, and that's the way it should be (in my opinion). If you want to learn C++ for the sake of learning unmanaged programming, then please, of course do it. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO, the *best* way to learn a new language is with a "pet project".

You will make mistakes, your code will be a mess, and you will look back at your mess and realize that you should throw the whole thing away.  BUT, you were excited with every incremental feature, and you enjoyed the "pet project" to the point where you could visualize it take shape.  It can serve as a good "straw-man" model to be the externally observable characteristics a useful system for when you start it again.

For C++, write a program that translates music scales up-or-down.  Generate a role-playing-game character.  Create a text adventure game.  There are zillions of options, but if you want to learn the language, and not a GUI library, then I'd stay with a command-line processing tool.

IMHO, C++ is a great way to think about how the computer works, and *every* design option is available to you.  I use many languages regularly, but C++ is one of my favorites, so I would (with bias) recommend you keep with your study of C++.

[UPDATE] Again, my bias, but IMHO if you are learning C++, then learn C++.  You may not want to start working with the Standard Template Library (STL) right now.  The iterators are weird, and you have to invert your brain away from the "typical" object-oriented model to use them.  They are "mathematically elegant", but they are not very object oriented, IMHO.  Yes, go ahead and use `std::vector<>` (because you shouldn't write your own `vector`), but that should be a "data member" within a "real" class that actually does something.  For example, `class MyGame` can have one-or-more data members that might be things like `std::vector<Player*>` and `std::vector<GameBoardSquare*>`.  (The goal is to wrap `std::vector<>` with "real" classes that you write, where your "real" classes represent your logical problem domain.)

Comment: @charley: `vector<Player>` is not a good idea; you will leak `Player` objects. Instead, it should be `vector<Player>` or (if `Player` objects are not readily copied) `vector<shared_ptr<Player> >`.

Comment: @Chris, fair point (on guard-against-vector-object-leaks). I tend to use containers-of-pointers and manually new/delete to manage the set, where `std::vector<>` is merely a convenient auto-resizing-vector-of-pointers. (That's why I almost always wrap `std::vector<*>` as a data member of some other class.)

Comment: @charley: You can wrap everything in a data type, but (to me at least) it gets too tedious after a while. I like things to be automatically done for me, and that's why I'm a big fan of smart pointers. :-)

Comment: Not everything OO is good, and not everything not OO is bad...

Comment: @FredOverflow, agreed, but C++ is an OO language (otherwise you'd use C). My preference is OO with class interfaces such that application code is very LISP-like (e.g., functional, "state is evil").

Comment: @Chris, true, wrapping logic into types *can* get tedious. However, the reason the types exist is because there are *rules* that govern the type and its behavior. If you don't have the type, then those rules are "sprinkled" throughout application code, rather than centralized to the type.

Comment: @charley: Sure, agree with centralising rules to the type, etc. However, if you don't use smart pointers, then you have lots of boilerplate for dealing with when pointers get deleted, etc. That's still more tedium than I want to deal with. Plus, the rules for smart pointers are (to a point) fairly straightforward and I wouldn't consider them "sprinkling".

Answer (score 6):

C++ is hard when you come from Java and C# because, being unmanaged, it has a totally different execution model compared to managed languages.

For example, rather than relying on a garbage collector to pick up unused objects for you, you need to use smart pointers so that they keep track of when to delete objects. Also, the notion of object deletion (and more generally, that objects have specific, finite lifetimes, unlike most managed languages) means that you have to know when an object has been freed or invalidated and cannot be touched again.

One example of this is with STL containers. You access these containers using iterators (think pointers on steroids), but there are very picky rules about when the iterators are invalidated. If you use a `vector`, for example, any time the vector has to be expanded, all existing iterators to it are invalidated and cannot be used any more. Seasoned C++ programmers know these rules like the backs of their hands, but it's a steep learning curve for a newcomer.

In other words, you have a lot of learning ahead of you. If you want to get into unmanaged programming, it's learning worth having, but the decision is yours. :-)

Comment: I can't imagine why a beginner would need smart pointers. What's harder to understand is why you shouldn't use pointers for everything (like seems natural when you come from Java).

Comment: @Brendan: You can use auto (stack) objects instead of allocated (heap) objects, but that's not suitable for every circumstance, for example, if you need objects that outlive the current scope.

Comment: Of course you need heap objects, but for the most part they're easy to keep track of. I can only think of one case off the top of my head when I've needed smart pointers (it was a networking program with classes with complex asynchronous workers). Deleting heap-allocated objects isn't any more complicated than closing resources in Java.

Comment: @Brendan: You know how in Java, you have to use `finally` a lot if you want to close resources in a robust fashion? In C++, you have to use RAII to achieve the same, and smart pointers is one of the simplest applications of RAII. :-)

Comment: I guess that's a good point. I'm not sure I agree that it's a good use of smart pointers, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @Brendan: Actually, RAII is _the_ motivating factor for creating smart pointers in the first place. It allows your program to be exception-safe. (Please, for your sanity, do not get me started on Google and Mozilla's policy of banning exceptions. :-P)

Comment: I understand the point of RAII, I just think smart pointers are more useful in situations where you don't know when a pointer will go out of scope (like complicated async code). If you know where to put the `delete`, just do a `delete`.

Comment: @Brendan: "Just do a `delete`": how do you propose to do that in an exception-safe fashion?

Comment: Hm.. I suddenly see your point. I forgot about the lack of `finally`.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel like I'm really ready to take the next step.

This 'next step' depends on where you want to go. If you want to delve more deeply into game programming, OS development, embedded systems, want to get more closer to the metal of the processor, or just want to learn some other languages to broaden your range of knowledge, then yes, learning C++ is a good next step. **But**, if the 'next step' you want to take is towards desktop development, server programming, web programming, etc, then C++ probably isn't the *best* choice. If you know where you want to go we can probably give you more relevant help. We can't tell you want language to use if you don't know what you want to with it.

> It really does take a lot more effort to learn and accomplish anything when using it

One of the big differences between C++ and java/C# is that you need to be a bit more verbose and things tend to be slightly less abstracted. However, this is what makes C++ what it is. If you took C++ and added some memory safety belts and baked several Object Oriented concepts (interfaces, final classes, generics, etc.) you would basically have something that resembles Java. Yes, this is an oversimplification, and it overlooks differences in how the programs are compiled and executed, but its a good way to think about them in the beginning.

In other words, you used to be driving a car from the driver's seat. You could still get where you wanted quickly and efficiently, and the normal things you'd want to do in a car have been provided for you. Now, you're still driving the car, but with all of the individual parts exposed. You have a **lot** more control now and can do many new things that Java did not allow you to. You have to know a bit more about what's going on to coordinate all the different parts of the car, but once you know how you can go a lot faster (get better performance from the computer because you're doing things more efficiently). It's not a perfect analogy, but it gives you the idea. You're having some speed bumps learning to use it, but once you master the new power you've been given you'll be a much better programmer and understand computers far more deeply.

> where should I start?

I would just get an introduction to programming book that uses C++. All of the material should be familiar to you, so you'll be able to focus on the syntax and things that are tripping you up. Once you get through that you can move on to something more advanced. [I've heard many good things about Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/), not the least of is that its 350 pages but packs as much details as a 600+ page book.

Good luck! (and don't forget that we're always here if you have any questions :D )

Comment: Thanks. I suppose where I really want to go is O.S. development and Game Programming. Those are where my interests truly lie. Web isn't really ma thang.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should answer a simple question: why do I need to learn C++? You'd be better thinking of learning concepts rather than languages. Are you already good enough with OOP? Maybe it's time to learn about design patterns? Or functional programming?

Another point is that you should distinguish between learning the syntax and frameworks/standard libraries. C++ is very flexible and low-level although it has lots and lots of nicely written library. But I'd better choose Java or Python whenever I need to do some xml processing rather than C++.

To be short, you basically know the syntax of C++ already. It won't take much time to switch from Java to C++ in this sense. Every programming language is just a tool. When you need to dig, you take a spade. When you need to make a hole, you take a drill.

Answer (score 0):

Look into QT:

http://qt.nokia.com/products/

You will need to grasp the basics first, but, it will allow you to quickly move into stuff which feels more advanced due to the output. QT supports Linux, Mac, and Windows. It allows creating cross-platform and working with the native OS as well. QT is a library for C++, though it is simple enough that one could begin learning C++ with QT, if so desired.

Comment: I'm not sure QT is the best way to learn C++, since it tends to use non-standard things (like its own foreach construct and its own string class).

Comment: While this may be true, none of this is required. You can certainly use QT with the STD libraries. Plus it certainly brings you into a more exciting C++ and closer to home when coming from JAVA.

Comment: I just feel like learning QT and learning C++ are different things..